# Is it safe to change name column in msdb sysjobs?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to rename a lot of similar named job names so i want to run an update statement to change the `name` column of `msdb..sysjobs`.

Editing system tables is something i am pretty aware of, but changing job names doesn't feel that dangerous, because i think the job_id is what counts. Is it safe to do it in this case?

I am using sql server 2008.

Comment: Use `sp_update_job` to do this. You can look at the definition of it yourself to see what it does. One comment in there indicates it has logic so "If the name was changed, make SQLServerAgent re-cache any alerts that reference the job since the alert cache contains the job name"

Comment: Inspecting the transaction shows there are several tasks processed when changing a value. I think it's safer to use `sp_update_job` with some logic to edit the jobs. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is NOT save to just rename it. Using sql profiler shows, that renaming a package using the object exlorer will start several procedures. It will create a new package using `sp_add_dtspackage` and drop it later using `sp_drop_dtspackage`. The package id is although set using a parameter, so setting it random really seems to be a potential risk.

Answer (score 1):

When you have the same jobs running in multiple environments, it's a better practice to refer to jobs by name rather than by ID, because a job with the same name will be created with a different ID in every environment.

If you change the name of the jobs, make sure that any scripts you use to manipulate those jobs also use the new name.

Comment: Good point, this is something i have to check, too. Besides that, what do think about manipulating msdb..sysjobs? That's important for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is nothing to worry about, you can modify it.
Please find detail about [sysjobs here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189817.aspx).